# Identify group member traits other than the focal observation {dplyr}

Tags: r

This is my sample data:

```
D <- data.frame(Family=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","c","c","c"),
           Name=c("Adam","Amy","Aaron","Bob","Brian","Brandon","Chris","Claire", "Chloe"),
           State=c("CA","PA","TX","CA","CA","CA","MA","MI","FL"),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  Family    Name State
1      A    Adam    CA
2      A     Amy    PA
3      A   Aaron    TX
4      B     Bob    CA
5      B   Brian    CA
6      B Brandon    CA
7      c   Chris    MA
8      c  Claire    MI
9      c   Chloe    FL
```

I need to make a function that identifies whether "Family members *other than the focal row in the same group*" lives in CA

I've tried

```
require(dplyr)
D1 <- D %>% group_by(Family) %>%
mutate(Family.in.CA = any(State=="CA"))


  Family    Name  State Family.in.CA
  <fctr>  <fctr> <fctr>        <lgl>
1      A    Adam     CA         TRUE
2      A     Amy     PA         TRUE
3      A   Aaron     TX         TRUE
4      B     Bob     CA         TRUE
5      B   Brian     CA         TRUE
6      B Brandon     CA         TRUE
7      c   Chris     MA        FALSE
8      c  Claire     MI        FALSE
9      c   Chloe     FL        FALSE
```

But my desired function needs Adam to be FALSE, Since in Adam's Family, nobody other than Adam lives in CA.

**UPDATE**

Since the OP is causing confusion, to elaborate, I'm trying to compare each row to other *rows in the same group*

```
#Adam checks whether Amy or Aaron is in CA == FALSE
#Amy checks whether Adam or Aaron is in CA == TRUE #Adam
#Aaron checks whether Adam or Amy is in CA == TRUE #Adam
#Bob checks whether Brian or Brandon is in CA == TRUE #Brian and Brandon
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `base R` to do this.  We `split` the dataset by 'Family', loop over the rows, check whether "CA" is `%in%` any of the "State" other than the current row, `unsplit` and get the output as a `vector`.

```
unsplit(lapply(split(D, D$Family), function(x) 
        sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) {
           x2 <- as.character(x$State[-i])
       "CA" %in% x2
        })), D$Family)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, this could be done in a one-line

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D)[, Family.in.CA := unlist(lapply(1:.N, function(i) "CA" %in% State[-i])), Family]
D
#   Family    Name State Family.in.CA
#1:      A    Adam    CA        FALSE
#2:      A     Amy    PA         TRUE
#3:      A   Aaron    TX         TRUE
#4:      B     Bob    CA         TRUE
#5:      B   Brian    CA         TRUE
#6:      B Brandon    CA         TRUE
#7:      c   Chris    MA        FALSE
#8:      c  Claire    MI        FALSE
#9:      c   Chloe    FL        FALSE
```

Comment: Adam does not have any family in CA, so he will be FALSE.  Amy does have family in CA, so she will be TRUE.  If the person has family members in CA, the variable should be TRUE.

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the prettiest `dplyr` code you've ever seen, but it gets the job done:

```
D %>% group_by(Family) %>%
    mutate(Family.in.CA = list(as.character(State))) %>%
    mutate(Family.in.CA =
       mapply(function(xx, yy) "CA" %in% yy[-match(xx, yy)], State, Family.in.CA))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: Family [3]
#
#  Family    Name  State Family.in.CA
#  <fctr>  <fctr> <fctr>        <lgl>
#1      A    Adam     CA        FALSE
#2      A     Amy     PA         TRUE
#3      A   Aaron     TX         TRUE
#4      B     Bob     CA         TRUE
#5      B   Brian     CA         TRUE
#6      B Brandon     CA         TRUE
#7      c   Chris     MA        FALSE
#8      c  Claire     MI        FALSE
#9      c   Chloe     FL        FALSE
```

It collects all the states a occupied by all family members from each family (first `mutate`).  Then, it removes (an instance of) the state the person in each row lives in from that collection and checks whether "CA" is in the remaining list, which represents the states of other family members.